# Can't install scipy

Tags: python, docker, scipy

I am trying to install `scipy` from a `Dockerfile` and I cannot for the life of me figure out how.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV HOME /root

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y gfortran
RUN apt-get install -y python-numpy
RUN apt-get install -y python-matplotlib
RUN apt-get install -y ipython
RUN apt-get install -y ipython-notebook
RUN apt-get install -y python-pandas
RUN apt-get install -y python-sympy
RUN apt-get install -y python-nose

# Install Python packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install cython

# Install scipy
RUN apt-get install -y python-scipy
```

This builds an image, but when I run the container and try to `import scipy` it says:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  9 2016, 03:30:07)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I have tried using `RUN pip install scipy` and `RUN pip install git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git` but those throw an error before completing the build.

Comment: To be honest, I am not familiar with docker. What prevents you from just running `pip install git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git` on terminal, besides the `numpy` dependency?

Comment: Don't you want `python3-scipy`? It appears that your system is defaulting to using Python3.

Comment: Or just `RUN pip install scipy`? Though you may want to double check that the `pip` you're using is indeed the Python 3.5 pip.

Comment: Docker just builds a self contained environment...so I'm starting with a Debian Jessie image, installing Python 3.5, then running the install commands in succession for the packages/modules.

Comment: @jdesilvio except you are installing all python2.x packages using `apt`.

Comment: `pip install python3-scipy` won't build either. i will run it again and tell you the error,

Comment: @Suever - that certainly sounds like an issue, this is the first time I'm building a Python 3 image. Do you know which packages need to be changed or how I can install them all as Python 3 packages?

Comment: @jdesilvio literally preface everything with "python3" i.e. `apt-get install python3-packagename` rather than `apt-get install python-packagename`

Comment: Built using `python3-<package>` can see `scipy` in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`but I still get the `No module named 'scipy'` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using Python 3 but installing the Python 2 packages. Change your `Dockerfile` to the following:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV HOME /root
ENV PYTHONPATH "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages"

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
        gcc \
        build-essential \
        zlib1g-dev \
        wget \
        unzip \
        cmake \
        python3-dev \
        gfortran \
        libblas-dev \
        liblapack-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
    && apt-get clean

# Install Python packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install \
        ipython[all] \
        numpy \
        nose \
        matplotlib \
        pandas \
        scipy \
        sympy \
        cython \
    && rm -fr /root/.cache
```

Comment: I still get `ImportError: No module named 'scipy'`

Comment: Yeah. There's an issue with the `PYTHONPATH`. Update coming shortly.

Comment: When using `apt-get install python3-numpy`, there's a bug inside the numpy package. So, I moved all the Python packages to `pip install`.

Comment: this throws `numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found`. Adding `apt-get install libopenblas-dev`.

Comment: I got it to work without `libatlas-base-dev`. Thanks!